# Dynamic query parameters in CXF web client

Tags: java, spring, apache, cxf

I want to add query parameters at run time traditionally we do it with url?a=b&b=c&so on..
but i dont know the parameters length so i want to add the query parameters dynamically 
How this can be done?

Comment: You should show us your code and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add any number of parameters to the [CXF WebClient](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html) using `WebClient.query(String, Object...)`.   For example, if you have a Map of parameters, you could do like something the following:

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("foo", "hello");
    params.put("bar", "world");

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://url"); 
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        webClient.query(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    Response res = webClient.get();
```

This will result in a GET request to `/url?foo=hello&bar=world`

Comment: I already got this ans ..i had found it yest ..but thanks for ur help and time.. :D